# Use 1 SharePoint list item to create an excel document

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, infopath, excel

So I have a SharePoint list, where each new item pulls up this form:

[image]

As you can see, it is already formatted like an excel sheet, is there a way to have this automatically be uploaded to an excel sheet after the approval process (in Flow) is completed?

I am trying to avoid having to copy each individual piece of data from each cell in the flow, so I was hoping I could create an excel file, especially since I can't copy list items anymore. (The online version won't let me revert to flow 2010)

---

I want each new item added to the list to become its own .xlsx file. There is already a way to give each file its own unique name, just want to create a properly formatted file out of a completed or blank document.

I would also accept an answer that shows me an easier way to carry this exact form over to another easily readable file type without having to copy each field one by one, and will still allow for everything to be edited should the need arise.